# "Error converting data type varchar to datetime"

Tags: sql-server

How can I solve the error in the following procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cards
    @salesman VARCHAR(10),
    @RCV10 INT,
    @RCV09 INT,
    @RCV15 INT,
    @GPRS15 INT,
    @RCV20 INT,
    @RCV25FTT INT,
    @RCV25 INT,
    @RCV31 INT,
    @RCV30 INT,
    @RCV35 INT,
    @RCV50 INT,
    @RCV55 INT,
    @SIM INT,
    @VTOPSIM INT,
    @VTOPBAL INT,
    @THREEGSIM INT,
    @entrydate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(
           SELECT *
           FROM   CardsIssued
           WHERE  salesman = @salesman
                  AND RCV10 > @RCV10
                  AND RCV09 > @RCV09
                  AND RCV15 > @RCV15
                  AND GPRS15 > @GPRS15
                  AND RCV20 > @RCV20
                  AND RCV25FTT > @RCV25FTT
                  AND RCV25 > @RCV25
                  AND RCV31 > @RCV31
                  AND RCV30 > @RCV30
                  AND RCV35 > @RCV35
                  AND RCV50 > @RCV50
                  AND RCV55 > @RCV55
                  AND SIM > @SIM
                  AND VtopSim > @VTOPSIM
                  AND VtopBal > @VTOPBAL
                  AND ThreeGSim > @THREEGSIM
                  AND EntryDate = @entrydate
       )
    BEGIN
        INSERT Cards_Returned
        VALUES
          (
            @salesman,
            @RCV10,
            @RCV09,
            @RCV15,
            @GPRS15,
            @RCV20,
            @RCV25FTT,
            @RCV25,
            @RCV31,
            @RCV30,
            @RCV35,
            @RCV50,
            @RCV55,
            @SIM,
            @VTOPSIM,
            @VTOPBAL,
            @THREEGSIM,
            @EntryDate
          )
    END
    ELSE
        PRINT'CARDS RETURNED CANNOT BE GREATER THAN CARDS ISSUED'
END
```

Run as:

```
execute cards 'S001',50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,'28/1/2013'
```

gives the following error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure cards, Line 0
Error converting data type varchar to datetime
```

Comment: When posting code, please highlight it and hit the `{}` button to make it readable and turn on syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 23):

`'28/1/2013'` is an ambiguous format - SQL Server might interpret it as `dd/mm/yyyy` or as `mm/dd/yyyy`. In this case, it's done the latter, and doesn't know what the 28th month of the year is.

Use `'20130128'` instead. This is *always* interpreted as `yyyymmdd`.

Comment: sorry its giving the following error...Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Procedure trgcards_return, Line 4
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: In case you are still getting the same error even using 'yyyymmdd' format check the date itself you are passing is correct. For example passing date '20201131' will raise the same error because the date of 31-Nov does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same error. In my case it was passing datetime2 value to a datetime column:

Had to change string to datetime (3 digits) instead of 7 digits for milliseconds:

```
exec [dbo].[UpdateProc] @LastViewDate='2016-07-27 11:03:04.1378957'
```

To:

```
exec [dbo].[UpdateProc] @LastViewDate='2016-07-27 11:03:04.137'
```

Comment: This answer fixed my errro.

Answer (score 2):

As per your error message, `problem is with the date format`. Format your *date* to `ISO format (yyyymmdd)` before execution as below.

```
execute cards 'S001',50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,'20130128'
```

Comment: its giving the error....Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Procedure trgcards_return, Line 4
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Can you execute this `select convert(varchar, dateadd(day,-3,getdate()),112)` and reply with the results?

Comment: `ISO format` works on any sql-server. if you try `select convert(datetime,'20130128')` will confirm you that. This error message is at `line 4` and your OP error message is at `line 1` which means the error is somewhere else. Make sure your date is `yyyymmdd` format. ie; YEAR(4 digits)MONTH(2 digits)DATE(2 digits)

Comment: the answer is...2013-01-28 00:00:00.000  plz let me know the exact line to change,as i am new to it and not getting it properly

Comment: This is a different stored procedure you are executing now. New error message says `Procedure trgcards_return` and it was `Procedure cards` before.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps try changing the input variable for @EntryDate to a varchar.
Then, when using it further down, perform a CONVERT(datetime,@EntryDate) on it.

Comment: its giving the error.. Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure neha, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: perhaps try something along the lines of CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar,@EnrtyDate, 112)).

This is happening as per Damien's comment, it is SQL not liking the format of the date...

Answer (score 1):

That would be datetime conversion 103 (dd/mm/yyyy):

```
--receive parameter as varchar <br/>
declare @dateEntry as varchar(10) <br/>
set @dateEntry= '28/1/2013' 

--do the conversion <br/>
declare @dateResult as datetime <br/>
set @dateResult = convert(datetime, @dateEntry, 103) <br/>
select @dateResult <br/>
```

Ref: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Answer (score 0):

Some more commentary .. and a different solution..

SQL Server Profiler is giving me dates as per example :

```
exec P707005CreateMemo '4142541','QRate',NULL,NULL,'2021-06-24 00:00:00'
```

Related question here:

[SQL Trace/Profiler - Ambiguous date format being displayed (.NET Core/EF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198137/sql-trace-profiler-ambiguous-date-format-being-displayed-net-core-ef)

SQL Server profiler seems to do this different date format for exec but not INSERT (for example) ..

**It seems that the solution to the SQL Server Profiler date values in exec statements is to add in the T in the date (manually).**

i.e.

```
exec P707005CreateMemo '4142541','QRate',NULL,NULL,'2021-06-24T00:00:00'
```